# understanding diverging to infinity

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm currently studying about sequence and infinity, but i don't understand something.
For example, Consider the series $a_n\:=\:n^3+90n\:+\:9$, and i want to show that: $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(a_n\right)\:=\:\infty $$
So, i go to the definition that say:

> $x_n\to\infty$ or $\lim_{n\to \infty }x_n=\infty$  if, for every $K$, there is an $N$ such that, for every $n\ge N$, $x_n>K$

i take arbitrary $K$ > $0$. Now, i know i need to find that $N$ as a "function" of $M$, but what to do? can someone guide me step by step? tnx a lot!

Comment: Easiest deduction would be $a_n>n$ for all $n$. So for $n\ge N$, we have $a_n>n\ge N$

Comment: Agreed with Swapnil.  You don't need to find the *smallest* $N$ such that $n\geq N\Rightarrow a_n>K$.  Any $N$ such that the statement is true works to show that the sequence diverges.  In particular in this case, $N=K$ works since $a_K=K^3+...>K$

Comment: Suggestion: stop using `\:` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $a_n>n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

So whenever $n\ge N$, we have $a_n>n\ge N$

Answer (score 0):

Often you want to find a sequence which is actually smaller than your given sequence, and for which it is easier to find $N$.

For this problem, define $b_n = n^3$. Then $a_n > b_n$. For $b_n$ the problem is easier: given $K$ you can take $N=\lceil \sqrt[3]{K} \rceil+1$. The important thing is the cube root; the rest of it is just to get an integer which is larger than the cube root. Now for $n \geq N$ you have $b_n \geq (\sqrt[3]{K}+1)^3>K$. Since $a_n > b_n$ we also have $a_n > K$ for $n \geq N$.